# Why does function expecting type alias input does not typechecks if I pass undelying type?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In the following code, why is the compiler not able to infer that **x1** is immutable when passed to function **imSeq**.

```scala
def imSeq(e: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int]) = e.foreach(println)

def mSeq(e: Seq[Int]) = e.foreach(println)

scala> val x1 = Seq(1, 2, 3)
x1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> x1.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]]
res11: Boolean = true

scala> x1.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int]]
res12: Boolean = true

scala> x1.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]]
res13: Boolean = false

scala> imSeq(x1)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[Int]
required: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int]
            imSeq(x1)
                ^
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have to be explicit here imSeq(immutable.Seq(1, 2, 3))

Comment: That comment should be part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you explicitly require an instance of [`immutable.Seq`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala) in your function, but the [pre-imported `Seq` trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala) is not just an alias for `immutable.Seq`, it's actually a base trait of `immutable.Seq`. In other words, [`immutable.Seq` extends `Seq`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L28).

Generalize the accepted type:

```
def imSeq(e: Seq[Int]) = e.foreach(println)
```